# Email notification when user visit website

Tags: smtp

I have a legacy website that has been hosted n running fine
. Now I want to send email notification with date and time, when user visit that site. I don't have the source code. Is it possible to send email without actually needing the source code. Any help would be appreciated. If u can show me the direction, u r a life saver.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you know about Google Analytics?** It wont send you email notification but it tracks and reports your website traffic. It also has a real time reporting API enables you to request real time data — for example, real time activity on your website.

visit: https://www.google.com/analytics/

It's very easy to setup.

Comment: All I want to know is the date time of the users. I was thinking of using clinetside  mailto to send email to my team lead before redirecting to that website. Is that a good approach?